# Can i import excel file but with dynamic row in laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, dynamic, import

I already understand passing variables or data from the controller to construct import files, but can I dynamically create import rows from my controller data?

Variable in the `controller` is like this:

```
$datas = App\Models\AssessmentFactor::all();
```

And in construct import file is like this:

```
$this->datas=$datas
```

And doing loop for get the row name in process is like below:

```
foreach ($datas as $key => $row) {
    (How to actually do it ?) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Laravel `maatwebsite/excel` with `composer require maatwebsite/excel`.
Follow the given link https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html